# Numbers satisfying $\binom{n}{k} = m!$

Tags: number-theory, combinatorics

Let $k,m,n\in \mathbb{N}$ where $1 < k < n-1$. Consider the equation $$\binom{n}{k} = m!$$ which can also be equivalently written as $$n!=(n-k)!k!m!$$ The only instances I found are $\binom{4}{2} = 3!$ and $\binom{10}{3} = 5!$ I do not see any pattern coming out. As I went far out, it seemed that it is hard to find other examples as the second instance seems to be related to the problem of  consecutive numbers being composed of only small primes.  Is it true that these are the only instances?

Thanks.

Comment: @Henry, thanks for the edit.

Comment: There is also ${16 \choose 2}=5!$.

Comment: @Henry, are there more that do not include small numbers such as 2?

Comment: I just wrote a script and I don't believe there are any others up to 13! (except of course $\binom{n}{0}$ and $\binom{n}{1}$).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're asking about the existence of factorials in entries of Pascal's triangle. I googled for *factorials pascal's triangle* and found this discussion:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17058/factorials-in-pascals-triangle

Comment: Thanks very much. I constructed the Pascal triangle to some extent while looking for examples but did not consider googling  in those terms.